# ffmpeg and VFR vs fixed

Tags: ffmpeg

I was changing some music videos from VFR to 30000/1001 using

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -i "C:\Temp\Faith Hill - The Way You Love Me.mp4" -c:v libx264 -crf:v 23 -filter:v fps="fps=30000/1001" -c:a ac3 -b:a 256k -ar 48000 "D:\Faith Hill - The Way You Love Me.mkv"
```

Using mediainfo, the file still appeared to be VFR and not the expected 29.97
ffprobe reported 30000/1001 and MPC reported 29.97.
I contacted mediainfo and was told it is a bug in ffmpeg, so now I am here.

Read all about it here - https://sourceforge.net/p/mediainfo/discussion/297609/thread/e0ef2ce9/?limit=25

Any thoughts on the chance of a bug in ffmpeg??

Comment: Try with `-r 30000/1001` instead of  `-filter:v fps="fps=30000/1001"`

Comment: No go with -r I get past duration 0.xxxx too large warnings... on every frame. I am trying to go from a VFR to a CFR, it is more or less working for me but curious why mediainfo still wants to see VFR. If you read the comments from mediainfo in the message on sourceforge you will see what is happening. what I want is to get it to a true CFR output.

Comment: You can ignore those warnings. Does the output show as VFR in mediainfo?

Comment: I can't ignore as I use the output to report my completed bits, ie 35 complete out 450 sec. the warning messes up the report. Go to sourceforge above and you can see the outputs of ffprobe,mediainfo and MPC.

Comment: you can try it yourself the cmd line is in my first post here is the video I am converting.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k900xmki4u6v354/AADRDHYasiG9N5_G1mmPEduGa?dl=0............ argh, I can't hit return for a new line it just sends my message.